How to implement in Karate API the Bearer Token authorization type?
I'm new in Karate and wanted to try this out. The web application endpoint that I'm currently working on has mostly all endpoints that need authentication.
How do I set up the Bearer Token authentication type in Karate?
I'm planning in VS Code.
In Postman, we set it up like this:




note that you may need to follow stack overflow guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask - I suggest you look at this page (search for oauth) https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-demo

Please make changes as per your api request. Here I am using https://airportgap.com/docs#api_ref_post_tokens api. In the background section, hitting the post request that will generate the token. From the response stored token value as a variable. The token value is passed as a header. Background section will execute before every scenario in the feature file. So the header passed will be used in subsequent get request mentioned in the scenario.
Feature: Bearer Token Authentication Feature

  Background: Hitting the api that will generate token
    * url 'https://airportgap.com/api/tokens'
    * request {"email": "emailvalue","password": "passwordvalue"}
    * method post
    * print 'response is:', response
    * def token = response.token
    * header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token

  Scenario: Bearer Token Authentication Scenario
    Given url 'https://airportgap.com/api/favorites'
    When method get
    And print 'response is:', response
    Then status 200

